What is the mean of $L_2^1$ and $C^{1+\frac{1}{2}}$ in PDE?
I see $L_2^1$ and $C^{1+\frac{1}{2}}$ in a paper, like picture below. From
$$
\int (\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2})^2 dx \le C
$$
I think that $\frac{dy}{dx}\in W^{1,2}$, where $W^{1,2}$ is Sobolev space. Since the dimension of $x$ is 1, we have $W^{1,2}\hookrightarrow C^{1/2}$, where $C^{1/2}$ is H"older Space.  So, we have $\frac{dy}{dx}\in C^{1/2}$. Therefore, $y\in C^{1,1/2}$.
I think the $L^1_2$ is $W^{1,2}$ and $C^{1+1/2}$ is $C^{1,1/2}$. Since I hardly ever learned PDE, I am not sure  whether my understand is right. So, ask here. Thanks.




If I recall correctly it means a function that is $C^{1}$ and whose first derivative is Holder continuous of order $1/2$ i.e $\lvert f(x) - f(y) \rvert \le K \lvert x - y \rvert^{1/2}$. I believe the answer here says as much. But don't quote me on it.

That seems right, although the notation $L_p^k = W^{k,p}$ seems odd as the inequality seems to suggest that $y\in W^{2,2}$, not $W^{1,2}$. Although it is possible that the author only needs $1,2$ regularity and is using a trivial embedding depending on the spatial domain
